# React JSX inline SVG on Codepen Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: reactjs, svg, jsx, codepen

I'm having `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` error on Codepen when trying to add this code, even thought i don't get such error on VSCode.

```
let App = () => {
      const handleClick = () => {
        let timeline = gsap.timeline();
          timeline.to(".flower_svg", {
            rotate: 45,
          });
      };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 60 60" className="flower_svg">
        <g transform="translate(55.5 193.5)">
          <path fill="#A65EC1" d="M-25.5-148.5v-15h-15c-8.3,0-15,6.7-15,15l0,0v15h15C-32.2-133.5-25.5-140.2-25.5-148.5L-25.5-148.5z"/>
          <path fill="#E3A6F1" d="M-10.5-163.5h-15v15c0,8.3,6.7,15,15,15h15v-15C4.5-156.8-2.2-163.5-10.5-163.5L-10.5-163.5z"/>
          <path fill="#A65EC1" d="M-10.5-193.5h15v15c0,8.3-6.7,15-15,15l0,0h-15v-15C-25.5-186.8-18.8-193.5-10.5-193.5L-10.5-193.5z"/>
          <path fill="#B7C6FD" d="M-40.5-193.5h-15v15c0,8.3,6.7,15,15,15l0,0h15v-15C-25.5-186.8-32.2-193.5-40.5-193.5L-40.5-193.5z"/>
        </g>
      </svg>

      <button onClick={() => handleClick()}>Rotate</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Anyone having this issue, you need to select the Babel Javascript Preprocessor from the Codepen JS settings

[image]